# C Character Set - Need Clarification

Tags: c++, c, character

I was reading the GCC C preprocessor -> Tokenization, in which it is mentioned that

> Preprocessing tokens fall into five broad classes:
>
> 1. identifiers
> 2. preprocessing numbers
> 3. string literals
> 4. punctuators
> 5. other.
>
> Any other single character is considered “other”.
>   It is passed on to the preprocessor's output unmolested.
>   The C compiler will almost certainly reject source code containing “other” tokens.
>   In ASCII, the only other characters are ‘@’, ‘$’, ‘`’, and control characters other 
>   than NUL (all bits zero).

I was also browsing the web and I came across 'C Character Set' in which they have mentioned '@' as one of the character.
Is the article which is mentioning '@' as one of the 'C Character Set' is wrong? or my understanding is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what you mean by "C Character Set". Can you please provide a reference to where you found the term?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: http://www.c4learn.com/character-set-in-c-programming.html

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Regretfully, there's absolutely no relation of what that link says to anything in the standard.  It's just someone's fantasy.  The standard says that "Physical source file characters are mapped, _in an implementation-defined manner_, to the basic source character set."  It further requires an implementation to recognize Unicode characters input as `"\uxxxx" or `"\Uxxxxxxxx"`, and explicitly says that it may represent these internally as Unicode, and not as a universal character name.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg With regards to the source file being portable... It's formally impossible, since one compiler might use EBCDIC, another UTF-8.  In practice, you _might_ want to restrict the source file to the 95 printable ASCII characters, plus line separators.  You'll need to transcode it for EBCDIC, but you'll probably have no problem reading it otherwise.

Comment: One reason `@` character should remain out of C is that it is used in Objective-C. And this is the only character to distinguish Objective-C from C. (Until recent spec. change in Objective-C but I’ll need to digress more.). Even if some compiler allow it it is not a good things.

Answer (score 2):

There are some compilers that allow "extra" characters, such as @ or $ as part of identifiers. This is not part of the standard, but extensions. From memory, it is mentioned in the C++ standard in a way that indicates that "a compiler may add extra characters".

Section 2.3:

> The basic source character set consists of 96 characters: the space
>   character, the control characters repre- senting horizontal tab,
>   vertical tab, form feed, and new-line, plus the following 91 graphical
>   characters:(14)

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
_ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ∼ ! = , \ " ’
```

> (Note 14: The glyphs for the members of the basic source character set
>   are intended to identify characters from the subset of ISO/IEC 10646
>   which corresponds to the ASCII character set. However, because the
>   mapping from source file characters to the source character set
>   (described in translation phase 1) is specified as
>   implementation-defined, an implementation is required to document how
>   the basic source characters are represented in source files.

Comment: But the standard also requires a compiler to accept universal
character names, as a means of inserting any Unicode character
into your program.  And the mapping between the input characters
from the file and the internal characters is implementation
defined.  On the other hand, `@` and `$` _are_ strictly
forbidden in identifiers.  Unlike `\u00E9`, or `\U00061234`.
(The first is `é`.  The second I have no idea, but the standard
says that it's allowed.)

Comment: G++ certainly doesn't accept `\u00e9` as part of a function name.

Comment: Then g++ isn't conformant.  The standard clearly says that it
must.  And this isn't a C++11 thing; this was the case way back
in C++98.  It's also the case for C90.  (I just tried, and
you're right.  This is a fairly inexcusable error, since the
requirement is now quite old.  VC++ has no problem with it.
VC++ also accepts it if generate a file in UTF-8 with `é`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: "`-fextended-identifiers` Accept universal character names in identifiers.  This option is experimental; in a future version of GCC, it will be enabled by default for C99 and C++."

Comment: @rici Thanks.  I did try `-std=c++11`, but was too lazy to look up other possible options.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that your question is completely clear.  Both the
C and the C++ standards require the compiler to support all of
the characters in Unicode, although not necessarily in
a transparent fashion: how the compiler maps input into its
internal character set is implementation defined.  But by this
definition, *all* compilers are required to accept `@`, `$`,
etc.

What you can do with any specific character is a different
question, and there are a lot of characters (like `@` and `$`)
which can only appear in a comment, a string literal or
a character literal (which resolves to a preprocessor number in
the text you quote).  Symbols, for example, may only contain `_`
and characters for which the Unicode type is a letter or a digit
(roughly speaking—the standard specifies exactly what
characters are and are not allowed).

Since how the implementation maps the characters in the
input to the source character set is implementation defined,
a compiler can map 0x40 (which would be a `@` in ASCII, Latin-1
or Unicode) to some other character, which is allowed in
a symbol.  I don't know of any which take this route; I suspect,
in fact, that a compiler which wanted to allow `@` or `$` in
a symbol would simply choose to be non-conformant, rather than
make it impossible to have the character in a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean the character set you get when you set `LANG=C`?

That's not the same thing at all. That's a *locale* that basically just says "use ASCII" with no special extras. It requires no extra translation files or terminal support. It just means you get the default output from everything.

---

Alternatively, maybe you really did mean the set of characters that may appear in a C program?

Don't forget that C programs may use those characters inside quotes. Just because they don't have a meaning in any language keyword or variable doesn't mean they can't exist in the file. On the other hand, it may be an error to include UTF-8 characters inside a C string, for example.

Just because a character is valid inside a C program, doesn't mean it's valid everywhere. The `if` keyword is not valid outside a function, for instance.

Comment: Preprocessor treats the tokens which are inside the quotes as point number 3 -> String literals.

Comment: @NishithJainMR: indeed, but those character are valid within a string token.

Comment: Yes, correct. But what I am talking about is other than string tokens. If I use '@' in an identifier or other place. What will happen? Will that be preprocessed as 'Other'?

Comment: Yes, if you create an identifier `abc@def`, the compiler will see that as *three* tokens, just as `abc+def` would. It will be a syntax error, of course.

Comment: @NishithJainMR That's what the text you quoted says (supposing that the text refers to standard C or C++).